# Protogen goroutine stack exceeds

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, code-generation

Recently i've run into a problem with code generation in golang. I have a huge proto file and now need to add logging to most of the messages, using external package. However, if i add logging for too many fields, generation panics, saying that goroutine stack exceeded. Is there a way to generate code by chunks, or increase goroutine max cache size for the generation only?

I tried to debug.SetMaxStack and run generate command with go code, but nothing changed, and it doesn't seem as a good solution for me

Comment: It is unlikely related to too much logging. You probably fell into a recursive printing loop. The stack dump should point to the problem.

Comment: @BurakSerdar it seems that recursive printing loop might be the problem, there is lot of repeating calls for innerFields in the stack dump. Is it possible to tell which fields are the problem? sadly, fast googling didn't give any results.

Comment: Look at the line numbers. The stack dump should have line numbers. There you might be able to figure out what's looping

Comment: @BurakSerdar I apologize for stupid question, but i feel like we mean different things talking about stack dump. After message with goroutine stack exceed there's stack trace with function calls in protogen package and lines, which lead to proto package. There is no traces leading to .proto file and problematic fields

Comment: It will not point you to .proto file. It will point you to the .go files where loop is happening.

Comment: Oh, i thought there was a simple solution. Anyway, thank you for help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was, as @BurakSerdar said in the comment recursive printing loop.
So if you have something like:

```
message human {
  string name = 1;
  human child = 2;
  human parent = 3;
}
```

You shouldn't do that:

```
message human {
  string name = 1;
  human child = 2 [(logger.field) = true];
  human parent = 3;
}
```

I believe the same goes about other custom things that you want to add to fields, if you have message, containing fields with the type of the same message